# Fourier Integral evaluation

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

We're doing fourier integrals in class, but unfortunately I have no idea how to even begin to tackle this one. The examples we have done in class were way simpler than this one:

$$
\int_0^\infty \dfrac {w^3\sin(xw)}{w^4+4}dw = \dfrac{1}{2}\pi e^{-x}\cos(x)
$$
when x > 0

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you originally trying to take the Fourier transform of $\dfrac{w^3}{w^4+4}$ and ended up here?

Comment: No, the above is what the problem looks like before any work.
I got stuck after applying A(w) and B(w) but after doing integration by parts, completing the integration by filling in infinity into w because there were sines and cosines

Comment: Can you use complex analysis?

Answer (score 3):

I would  take its Fourier sine transform of $e^{-x}\cos x$ and see that it's consistent with what's on the left. 
$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\cos x \sin w x\,dx
=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\frac{e^{iwx}-e^{-iwx}}{2i}\,dx$$
Multiply out exponentials and evaluate: 
$$\frac{-1}{4i}\left(\frac{1}{-1+i+iw}-\frac{1}{-1+i-iw}+\frac{1}{-1-i+iw}-\frac{1}{-1-i-iw}\right)$$
Which collects into 
$$\frac{-1}{4i}\left(\frac{-2iw}{(-1+i)^2+ w^2}+\frac{-2iw}{(-1-i)^2+ w^2} \right)$$
simplifies to
$$\frac{w}{2}\left(\frac{1}{-2i + w^2}+\frac{1}{2i+ w^2} \right)$$
and boils down to 
$$\frac{w}{2} \frac{2w^2}{4 + w^4} $$